# What do you call the jewelry that's attached to clothes?

Tags: word-request

I'm referring to something like this:

[image]

Or they are just called jewelry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the type of jewelry. Those look like beads or sequins, possibly both. From M-W:

> [Definition of bead for English Language Learners](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bead)
>   : a small, usually round piece of glass, wood, stone, etc., that has a hole through its center and that is put on a string with other similar pieces and worn as jewelry or that is sewn onto clothing
>   [Definition of sequin for English Language Learners](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequin)
>   : a small piece of shiny metal or plastic that is sewn onto clothes as a decoration

I found a [link](http://okbridal.storenvy.com/collections/977661-long-prom-dress/products/12973378-champagne-beaded-prom-dress-long-2017-prom-dress-sexy-prom-dress-dresses) with this particular picture and they call the dress "Champagne Beaded Prom Dress".

As @m_a_s points out, there are also rhinestones:

> [Definition of rhinestone for Students](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhinestone)
>   : a small imitation gem used in jewelry or for decoration

Comment: Don't forget rhinestones.

Comment: I see. So they're called jewelry.

Comment: @alex Yes, you can call them jewelry, but that's a broad term. It does not imply that it is used on clothing.

Comment: @alex  My wife works as a professional tailor, so we see many gowns like the one in the picture.  What you see there is called **beading**; the dress is **beaded**.  "Jewelry" is just wrong: jewelry means separate pieces like necklaces, rings, bracelets, etc., not things that are part of clothing.

Comment: @stangdon This should be an answer!